# will it break the react-redux design to create method which called in other action creator?

Tags: react-redux

I don't know if we should stick to the react-redux style all the time.

With react-redux, we put logic to the action creator, no matter simple action or async request. however, it indeed helps us to keep the work flow simple and clear:dispatch a action, and reducer to process the action to change data in store.

but I am curious about:

**can I create a function which is not an action creator? does this break the redux design?**

for example：

**action-creator-1.js**

```
const getData=()=>(dispatch,getState)=>{
    return Promise.resolve().then(()=>{
       //do long-running work
    });
};
export default{
  getData
};
```

**action-creator-2.js**

```
import action1 from 'action-creator-1';
const loadData=()=>(dispatch,getState)=>{
     return Promise.resolve().then(()=>{
         //? return action1.getData();
     })
     .then(()=>{
        //do other work
     })
}
```

can we set getData a simple function in action creator file:

```
const getData=(state)=>{
    return Promise.resolve().then(()=>{
       //get local data
    })
}
```

can this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Actions are payloads of information that send data from your application to your store. They are the only source of information for the store. You send them to the store using `store.dispatch()`.

In `action.js`

```
import {serviceCall} from './service-call';

export function showLoader() {
    return {
        type: 'SHOW_LOADER',
        payload: true
    };
}

export function loadData() {
    Store.dispatch(showLoader());
    return {
        type: 'SET_WIDGET_DATA',
        payload: return Promise.resolve().then(response => {
            return response
        })
    }
}

export function getData() {
    Store.dispatch(showLoader());
    return {
        type: 'GET_PAGE_DATA',
        payload: return Promise.resolve().then(response => {
            Store.dispatch(loadData());
        })
    }
}
export function serviceCall() {
    Store.dispatch(showLoader());
    return {
        type: 'GET_HTTP_DATA',
        payload: serviceCall({
            url: 'http://'
        })
    }
}
```

**can I create a function which is not an action creator? does this break the redux design?** ==> yes this will not break your redux design as we also create another .js file for http call like service.js.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I need this kind of method just in order to reuse the continuing process logic,  if the method just do memory calculation instead of http request, it is more useful and simple  as opposed to action creator, though it is weird to define in action creator file.